# Control Center view

Tags: ios, swift

Am trying to create a view like control centre in iPhone. As per my requirement the view have to be at bottom when user swap up, View need to be present from bottom to top, while dismissing view need to be swap bottom.Exactly like control centre I need a view, Can Anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that by the following code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

    var viewControlCenter : UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        createControlCenterView()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    // MARK: - Gesture Methods

    @objc func respondToSwipeGesture(sender: UIGestureRecognizer? = nil) {
        if let swipeGesture = sender as? UISwipeGestureRecognizer {
            switch swipeGesture.direction {
            case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.up:
                if self.viewControlCenter.frame.origin.y != 0 {
                    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
                        self.viewControlCenter.frame.origin.y = 0
                    }, completion: nil)
                }
                break
            case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.down:
                if self.viewControlCenter.frame.origin.y == 0 {
                    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
                        self.viewControlCenter.frame.origin.y = self.view.frame.size.height
                    }, completion: nil)
                }
                break
            default:
                break
            }
        }
    }

    @objc func onViewTapped(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer? = nil) {
        if self.viewControlCenter.frame.origin.y == 0 {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
                self.viewControlCenter.frame.origin.y = self.view.frame.size.height
            }, completion: nil)
        }
    }

    // MARK: - Custom Methods

    func createControlCenterView() {
        viewControlCenter = UIView.init(frame: self.view.bounds)
        self.viewControlCenter.frame.origin.y = self.view.frame.size.height

        let viewBG : UIView = UIView.init(frame: self.view.bounds)
        viewBG.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.6)
        viewControlCenter.addSubview(viewBG)

        self.view.addSubview(viewControlCenter)

        let swipeUp = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(respondToSwipeGesture(sender:)))
        swipeUp.direction = .up
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeUp)

        let swipeDown = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(respondToSwipeGesture(sender:)))
        swipeDown.direction = .down
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeDown)

        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(onViewTapped(sender:)))
        tap.delegate = self
        viewControlCenter.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
    }
}
```

Comment: Its works fine, But iPhoneX safe area is not covered by this.